# Make shared folder on Ubuntu through HTTP

Tags: file-sharing, https, lighttpd

I have a working project on Android, where there are a http-server and client. Client sends GET and POST request to the server and so downloads and uploads files from the server. Now I want to create such system on Ubuntu. I need a simple http-server and client requests to share files between two Ubuntu-computers. How could I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why use an http server and client when you can use Ubuntu One if it simply file sharing that you need?

In any case, if you really want such a system, you could try installing Apache with `sudo apt-get install apache2`.

More information here: https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/serverguide/httpd.html